# R: Kernel Density Plots (Bandwidth Must be Strictly Positive)

Tags: r, 3d, plotly, data-visualization, kernel-density

I am using the R programming language. I am following this tutorial over here for making 3d kernel density plots in R: https://plotly.com/r/3d-surface-plots/:

```
library(MASS)
library(plotly)

kd <- with(MASS::geyser, MASS::kde2d(duration, waiting, n = 50))
fig <- plot_ly(x = kd$x, y = kd$y, z = kd$z) %>% add_surface()

fig
```

I decided to try this on my own data :

```
#generate data
a = rnorm(100,10,10)
b = rnorm(100,5,5)
c = rnorm(100,5,10)
d = data.frame(a,b,c)

#make 3d plot (I think n = 50 refers to selecting the first 50 points?)
kd <- with(d, MASS::kde2d(a,b,c, n = 50))
fig <- plot_ly(x = kd$x, y = kd$y, z = kd$z) %>% add_surface()
```

But this results in the following error:

```
Error in MASS::kde2d(a, b, c, n = 50) : 
  bandwidths must be strictly positive
```

This error prevents me from creating the "kd" object.

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong? Is there a problem with the specific data I am using? Or is this a syntax error?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error using geom\_density\_2d() in R : Computation failed in \`stat\_density2d()\`: bandwidths must be strictly positive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53075331/error-using-geom-density-2d-in-r-computation-failed-in-stat-density2d-b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding the purpose of `kde2d`. From `help(kde2d)`:

> Two-dimensional kernel density estimation with an axis-aligned bivariate normal kernel, evaluated on a square grid.

From the same help file regarding the `h` argument:

> h
> vector of bandwidths for x and y directions. Defaults to normal reference bandwidth (see bandwidth.nrd). A scalar value will be taken to apply to both directions.

You are passing `c`, a length 100 numeric vector as `h`. You appear to be trying to pass data to `h`, this does not make sense. Pass either one or two values for bandwidth or nothing and accept the default.

From lines 31 and 32 of the [source](https://github.com/cran/MASS/blob/73aa67cfcb18f2b1ae1bb37e9287bf5430257b75/R/kde2d.R#L31-L32), we can see why you got the error:

```
    if (any(h <= 0))
        stop("bandwidths must be strictly positive")
```

Thus, if either of the first two values of `c` are negative or zero, you will get this error.

---

The `n` argument, as described in the help file:

> n
> Number of grid points in each direction. Can be scalar or a length-2 integer vector.

This determines the grid that the density is provided. If you provide a single value, a square grid is produced.

Comment: thank you for your answer! does that mean if i say (please remove the semi colons ; they are just intended to show spacings) : a = rnorm(100,10,10);
b = rnorm(100,5,5);
c = rnorm(100,5,10);
d = data.frame(a,b,c);
d = abs(d);

kd <- with(d, MASS::kde2d(a,b,c, n = 50));
fig <- plot_ly(x = kd$x, y = kd$y, z = kd$z) %>% add_surface(); this will fix the problem?

Comment: does "n = 50" mean that only the first 50 points are being used?

Comment: I've edited the answer to try and clear up your confusion, `h` is an argument for bandwidth, not data.

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications. Can you please take a look at this question if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65996674/r-plot-axis-display-values-larger-than-the-original-data thanks